# Asus Sabertooth 990FX RAID - Drives disappear

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid

Just got a 990fx 2.0. I'd like to setup two Seagate 1TB drives in a RAID 1 config and same thing: Detected under AHCI but as soon as the SATA ports are config'd to RAID, they aren't detected. I don't have CTRL+F as an option during POST.

Going round in circles and am not seeing the solution.

Am I expecting too much? Used to server class RAID hardware config's, so do desktop RAID controllers not operate similarly? In the sense that the hardware presents a logical drive to the OS, abstracted from the physical?

Should just work, so what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made any headway on this?